# ssrs report sum is not populating correctly

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a ssrs report have 3 Tablix using the same data set with different rate class, first Tablix have data for "ST" rate class,second Tablix have data for "SL" rate class and third Tablix have data for :PR" rate class. Each Tablix have a field Refund amount that field have pull the data from database table and sum on basis of the rate class group and the same process we repeat for all three Tablix
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mWnn.png)

Now when I am trying to sum for all three refund amount field value ,it only picking the value from the first table and displaying the multiply of 3 of first value.

I am using below code for the sum of these three field value.

=(ReportItems!StandardRefundTotal1.Value+ReportItems!tandardRefundTotal2.value+ReportItems!tandardRefundTotal3.Value)

Comment: Since you are using the same dataset, you can use a single tablix and group on rate class